# Xamarin iOS post image to Instagram

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiimage, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Goal: Using an iOS native method, push a user made picture onto their Instagram feed in C#.

```
public bool ShareImage(byte[] imageByte)
        {
            bool result = false;

            //string fileName = "xxx.png";
            //string path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fileName);
            //File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageByte);
            NSData data = NSData.FromArray(imageByte);
            UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
            
            //NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString($"instagram://library?AssetPath={path}"); // Only opens
            NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString($"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier={1}");
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(url))
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

As far as I'm aware the way I have to do this is to save my image to the device and get a Local Identifier for this.
I have constructed this from the snippets of objective-c code I have seen. Sharing photos only works with the native app installed, as I have learnt from my trials to get the facebook module working.

**Edit**: Using PHAssetChangeRequest from the iOS Photos namespace does not work.
A collegue has pointed out to me about the possibility of saving then using a photo picker to get the PHAsset for the Local Identifier. But this is an extra step I do not want the users of the App to go through. Better to just remove Instagram support as I just can go through the generic share method as shown below. The disadvantage of this method is that the user has then to pick the medium to share over.

```
public async void ShareImage(byte[] imageByte)
        {
            string fileName = "xxx.png";
            string path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fileName);
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageByte);
            await Share.RequestAsync(
                new ShareFileRequest()
                {
                    File = new ShareFile(path),
                    Title = "xxx"
                }
                );
        }
```

**Edit 2**
Tried a different way using UIDocumentInteractionController but it is showing nothing and not posting, it is not throwing any exceptions to give me any clues as to what I'm doing wrong.

```
public bool ShareImage(byte[] imageByte)
        {
            bool result = false;

            string fileName = "xxx.igo";
            string path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fileName);
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageByte);
            //string caption = "xxx";
            string uti = "com.instagram.exclusivegram";
            UIImageView view = new UIImageView();
            //UIDocumentInteractionController controller = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString(path));
            UIDocumentInteractionController controller = new UIDocumentInteractionController
            {
                //controller.Url = NSUrl.FromString(path);
                Url = NSUrl.FromFilename(path),
                Uti = uti
            };
            //CoreGraphics.CGRect viewDimensions = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
            
            _ = controller.PresentOpenInMenu(CoreGraphics.CGRect.Empty, view, true);
            //_ = controller.PresentOpenInMenu(viewDimensions, view, true);
            return result;
        }
```

**Edit 3**
Using

```
UIView view = new UIImageView();
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController is UIViewController uiController && uiController.View != null)
            {
                view = uiController.View;
            }
```

I was able to get the possible share options to show. I was logged in to Instagram using the native App, but the post did not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change

   `Url = NSUrl.FromFilename(path)`

   to

   `Url = new NSUrl(path,false)`

   **The second way is pointing to the correct file path not the file name .**
2. Change

   `controller.PresentOpenInMenu(CoreGraphics.CGRect.Empty, view, true);`

   to

   `controller.PresentOptionsMenu(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds, (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).Window, true);`

   **Show `UIDocumentInteractionController`  inside current Window and set the proper frame.**

Comment: I have changed the url initialisation.

But with presenting, the issue is that the class itself is called from Xamarin, and has no knowledge of a UIImageView and no reference to use. Unless there is also a way to get that somehow.

Comment: Are you developing Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.iOS ?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms. This is a native iOS class(public class ShareServiceInstagramiOS : IShareServiceInstagram) that is called from a Xamarin page. I have to implement both iOS and Android versions which is why I only send the image. The image itself is altered using Skia, and the byte[] comes from this.

Comment: Check my update code , change `View` to current Window.

Comment: Still nothing. I must be doing something wrong at a deeper level. The Window is there, the bounds have the same bound value as the window. It is unlikely a problem with the Xamarin overlaying the native iOS. The dimensions for a camera preview which also runs native and full-screen has the same bound dimensions. The Android version is using an Intent and has a much different layout, so is not helpful here either.

Comment: If possible could you provide us a basic , reproducible project to test ? Since it is working on my side . You can simply upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: Unfortunatly a basic reproducable App without all the other stuff and without customer secrets is currently a lot of extra work. Since this works only partially I shall have to convince the customer to go down the default path (shown in my first Edit). Thank you for your help to try and correct this for me.